# Script to read 1 line then move on to second once script has finished and repeat

Tags: python

Good afternoon,

I have a very odd request. i am trying to script to help with configs for vlans for work. what i would like it to do is read line 1 complete rest of script. then go back and read line 2... complete rest of script and so on and so forth until completed.

this is my current config

```
file=open("C:\\Users\\KM003308023\\final.txt","w")
file.write("")
file=open("C:\\Users\\KM003308023\\final.txt","a")
interface= open ("C:\\Users\\KM003308023\\int.txt")
pull= open ("C:\\Users\\KM003308023\\int.txt")


y= str(input("enter Port description:"))
p= str(input("Enter DATA vlan:"))
x= str(input("Enter voice vlan:"))
portconfig= "\n switchport port-security \n switchport port-security maximum 3 \n switchport port-security aging time 30 \n switchport port-security violation restrict \n switchport port-security aging type inactivity \n no logging event link-status \n no cdp enable \n spanning-tree portfast \n spanning-tree bpduguard enable \n no shut\n!\n"

output=""

for j in pull.readlines():
    output=(output + "default int " + j + "!\n")


for f in interface.readlines():
    output =(output + "int " + f +"description " + y + "\n switchport \n switchport access vlan " + p + "\n switchport mode access \n switchport voice vlan " + x + portconfig)

file.write(output)

file.close()
```

what i would like it to do is

1. pull readline1 from int.txt
2. output default int xxx
3. continue to second part
4. line 1
5. where it again readlines1 and outputs all the garbage needed.

example of current output:

```
default int fa 2/0/15
!
default int fa 7/0/1
!
default int fa 7/0/8
!
int fa 2/0/15
description UHC_VLAN2
 switchport 
 switchport access vlan 52
 switchport mode access 
 switchport voice vlan 53
 switchport port-security 
 switchport port-security maximum 3 
 switchport port-security aging time 30 
 switchport port-security violation restrict 
 switchport port-security aging type inactivity 
 no logging event link-status 
 no cdp enable 
 spanning-tree portfast 
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable 
 no shut
!
int fa 7/0/1
description UHC_VLAN2
 switchport 
 switchport access vlan 52
 switchport mode access 
 switchport voice vlan 53
 switchport port-security 
 switchport port-security maximum 3 
 switchport port-security aging time 30 
 switchport port-security violation restrict 
 switchport port-security aging type inactivity 
 no logging event link-status 
 no cdp enable 
 spanning-tree portfast 
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable 
 no shut
!
int fa 7/0/8
description UHC_VLAN2
 switchport 
 switchport access vlan 52
 switchport mode access 
 switchport voice vlan 53
 switchport port-security 
 switchport port-security maximum 3 
 switchport port-security aging time 30 
 switchport port-security violation restrict 
 switchport port-security aging type inactivity 
 no logging event link-status 
 no cdp enable 
 spanning-tree portfast 
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable 
 no shut
!

What i would like to see:

default int fa 2/0/15
!
int fa 2/0/15
description UHC_VLAN2
 switchport 
 switchport access vlan 52
 switchport mode access 
 switchport voice vlan 53
 switchport port-security 
 switchport port-security maximum 3 
 switchport port-security aging time 30 
 switchport port-security violation restrict 
 switchport port-security aging type inactivity 
 no logging event link-status 
 no cdp enable 
 spanning-tree portfast 
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable 
 no shut
!
default int fa 7/0/1
!
int fa 7/0/1
description UHC_VLAN2
 switchport 
 switchport access vlan 52
 switchport mode access 
 switchport voice vlan 53
 switchport port-security 
 switchport port-security maximum 3 
 switchport port-security aging time 30 
 switchport port-security violation restrict 
 switchport port-security aging type inactivity 
 no logging event link-status 
 no cdp enable 
 spanning-tree portfast 
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable 
 no shut
!
```

and so on until it runs out of lines.

I am new to this so trying to still get my Barrings.

Comment: This question might be poorly written, but downvoting it without adding a comment and explaining what is missing and how should question be edited is just rude.

Comment: Can you explain these steps (1. pull readline1 from int.txt, 2. output default int xxx, 3. ..., 4. ...., 5. ....) a little bit better. I don't understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You open the same file in two different variables `pull` and `interface`.
Just open it once, in one variable.

You do not need to typecast the result of `input` to `str`, because it returns a string.

You do not need to open file "final.txt" twice (once with "w", and second with "a").

You should not accumulate output in a variable, then write it all at once.

Finally, avoid writing very long lines; split them to improve readability.

This gives (I was not able to test it, since I do not have access to your files) the following code:

```
y= input("enter Port description:")
p= input("Enter DATA vlan:")
x= input("Enter voice vlan:")

portconfig = "\n".join([
  " switchport port-security ",
  " switchport port-security maximum 3 ",
  " switchport port-security aging time 30 ",
  " switchport port-security violation restrict ",
  " switchport port-security aging type inactivity ",
  " no logging event link-status ",
  " no cdp enable ",
  " spanning-tree portfast ",
  " spanning-tree bpduguard enable ",
  " no shut",
  "!\n"
])

with open("C:\\Users\\KM003308023\\final.txt","w") as out_file:
  out_file.write("")
  with open ("C:\\Users\\KM003308023\\int.txt","r") as inp_file:
    for j in inp_file.readlines():
      out_file.write("default int " + j)
      out_file.write("!\n")
      out_file.write("int " + j)
      out_file.write("description " + y)
      out_file.write("\n switchport \n switchport access vlan " + p)
      out_file.write("\n switchport mode access \n switchport voice vlan " + x)
      out_file.write(portconfig)
```